# How to configure and call the RSDL or WADL for REST web service?

Tags: rest, wadl

I want to implement the RSDL or WADL for REST webservice. I got the syntax for it from wiki, but not able to configure it in project. Can anyone tell me how the configuration is done and how to call. Basically how it works as far as workflow is concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used Jersey for REST webservice implementation. And Jersey auto generates the WADL for the web service. In order to access the WADL, you need to just append the '/application.wadl' to your REST base URL.
For example: "http://www.companyname.com/rest/application.wadl"